Ubuntu server 22.04 install chromium
I tried to install NagiosXI on Ubuntu but its crashed by chromium
 libharfbuzz-subset0 : Depends: libharfbuzz0b (>= 5.1.0) but 2.7.4-1ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tryiet install manually but the problem is always the same. Fixing packeges not solving the problem. Rebooting creates new problem with PDO
